# traceback.format_exc/print_exc returns None when expecting traceback

Tags: python, exception

I can't figure out why traceback.format_exc() is returning "None" in the following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import traceback

def my_excepthook(type, value, tb):
    print type.__name__
    print value
    # the problem: why does this return "None"?
    print traceback.format_exc(tb) # see http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc

sys.excepthook = my_excepthook # see http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook

# some code to generate a naturalistic exception
a = "text"
b = 5
error = a + b
```

Using Python 2.7.1, I get the following output:

```
TypeError
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
None
```

Instead of "None" on the 3rd line, I'd expect to get what happens when I comment out the sys.excepthook line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log-test.py", line 17, in <module>
    error = a+b
```

Comment: Look at the docs for format_exc - you don't need to pass `tb` as an argument. You might have meant to use `format_tb(tb)` instead.

Comment: Thomas K, you're right, `format_exc()` takes an optional limit, _not_ a traceback object. The code above came at the end of A LOT of trial and error (me trying things the way I wanted them to work). In the Python docs I find myself frequently confused by `module.function()` vs. `object.function()` and spent a lot of time scratching my head as to why `tb.format_exc()` didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change like this in my_excepthook:

```
print "".join(traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb))
```

Comment: PasteBT, thanks, you nailed it. (Guess I had been assuming the solution was going to be easier/more obvious).